VB.net string comparison with Powershell return output
I will try my best to ask the question.
Here is an abstract of the function.
Dim testPath = "Test-Path 'H:\General\H5841\"
Dim removeDir = "Remove-Item 'H:\General\H5841\"

result = RunScript($"{testPath}{payType}_{payrunNum}_{trials}_{ProcessingDate_DTP.Text}'")

If String.Compare(result, "True") Then
   RunScript($"{removeDir}{payType}_{payrunNum}_{trials}_{ProcessingDate_DTP.Text}'")
   Output_RTB.Text = "Folder Deleted"
Else
   Output_RTB.Text = "Folder Not Found"
End If

First, the function tests if the path is valid. Below is what the result will equal and it is working in Powershell, true if folder is found, else false. This is working.
Test-Path 'H:\General\H5841\G7_999_Final_29.03.24'
However, say when I tests it, the folder exists, and I run this function, it deletes the folder and prompts Folder Deleted but when I try to simulate that the folder is not there, it returns as False but it still shows Folder Deleted, instead of Folder Not Found.
When I start off without creating the folder, it returns False and Folder Not Found. I am not sure why this is behaving like this.
I also tried the conventional way of result is "True" and it is will go into the False condition despite the folder is there. I used MsgBox to prompt the result variable and also used a textbox to test for white spacing and it appears none.
If result Is "True" Then
   RunScript($"{removeDir}{payType}_{payrunNum}_{trials}_{ProcessingDate_DTP.Text}'")
   Output_RTB.Text = "Folder Deleted"
Else
   Output_RTB.Text = "Folder Not Found"
End If

PS: the curly braces are string interpolation that grab strings from variables and form controls in VB.net before converting into a PowerShell command.
Do you know why VB.net does not do logical comparison properly or is there a different approach I can take?
Thanks in advance

String.Compare returns an integer, but what you need for an If statement is a boolean. VB will make something up if you let it, but you don't want that. If you set Option Strict On for this project (and set it as the default for new projects) then Visual Studio can point out problems like that for you.

To add to Andrew's comment: Use If String.Compare(result, "True") = 0 Then ... or simply If result = "True" Then .... Note that the comparison is case-sensitive in both cases, but it's easy to make the former case-insensitive. The is operator only makes sense for comparing object references.

Hi @mklement0 Thanks, I did try to use the = operator and when the folder exists, it would still goes to false condition and prompt folder not found. I think there is a glitch with VB.net and Option Strict On may be the solution for it. However, other commands like Invoke-Item, if folder exist, the command is a True and file explorer opens the folder. VB.net is ok with comparing the String True/False with what was returned by that command. Interesting

@Kinny, perhaps the PowerShell code snippet that the Test-Path call is a part of returns more than just a Boolean value, in which case the comparison won't work as expected.  Given PowerShell's implicit output behavior - where you actively have to suppress return values / command output you don't want to be "returned" (became part of the output), this is a common problem. Without seeing what your RunScript function does and without seeing a representative, expanded code snippet, the problem is impossible to diagnose.

Why are you using PowerShell for that? Can't you just do something like this:
Option Strict On

Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnOkay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOkay.Click
        Dim folderPath As String = txtFolderPath.Text
        Output_RTB.Text = TryDeleteFolderAndReportSuccess(folderPath)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function TryDeleteFolderAndReportSuccess(folderPath As String) As String
        Try
            If DeleteFolder(folderPath) Then Return $"Folder '{folderPath}' deleted."
            Return $"Folder '{folderPath}' not found!"
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return $"Folder '{folderPath}' could not be deleted! The following error occurred: {ex.Message}"
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Shared Function DeleteFolder(folderPath As String) As Boolean
        Try
            Directory.Delete(folderPath, recursive:=True)
            Return True
        Catch ex As DirectoryNotFoundException
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

End Class


Thanks Chris for your contribution of this different approach. I was using powershell because I have a bunch of PS commands that I want to use interchangably with the frontend controls. For now I have used your recommendation for this process.
